# Windows 10 password is in english but I have only Greek now

Tags: windows-10, language, login-screen

I just bought a new Lenovo laptop (B50-80 80ew03d9uk ) with preinstalled windows 10. I am using a password with latin characters.

The user interface was in English and as a Greek user I tried to change the language. What I did, it was to remove the English language.

The result was a big mess with the login process. The computer start up language seems to be the Greek one and in order to enter my password (which uses latin characters) I must change the language to English. But this option has gone after my settings change and now I cannot use my computer.

Any advice on how to solve my problem?

Theo.

Comment: Even on a greek keyboard, you should be able to enter *any* character using the ALT and numeric keys. That will be a pain for the whole password, but you only have to do it once (assuming you will correct the problem after you are in)

Comment: How can I do this? The password is ktl64!

Answer (score 1):

No matter what keyboard is selected, you are always able to enter any character using the ALT and numeric keys.

That will be a pain for the whole password, but you only have to do it once (assuming you will correct the problem after you are in).

Check http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code for details on how to it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try holding the Windows key and pressing space; this should cycle through langauges you have installed. Perhaps Windows 10 kept the language settings only in the login?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work!

Comment: Oh well. Sorry about that.